# MySQL Rows inserted just disappear

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

Here is the scenario:

**UPDATED**
Thanks to anakata for pointing out table locks and problems with overlapping sessions.

Start Transaction
Run a bunch of queries, these 2 in particular (private data removed):

```
START TRANSACTION

... various select statements...

INSERT INTO `leads` (`vertical_id`, `offer_id`, `campaign_id`, `affiliate_id`, `creative_id`, `is_test`, `ignoreme`, `qualified`, `usid`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, `ip_address`, `referrer`, `duplicate_hash`, `address2`, `form_message`, `microtime`, `created`, `sub_id`, `score`, `imported`, `buyer_price`, `purchased_price`) VALUES ('45', '82', '151', '3', '0', 0, 0, 1, '0510', 'CharXX', 'MXX', 'XXXXX@yahoo.com', '451 XXX', 'Hagerstown', 'MD', '21740', '301-------', '405877318', 'X', 'e0534ea843c35d0f300ed4ff6e65b8db', '', 'redacted', '1368665153.6829', NOW(), '333', 0, 0, '0', '0')

INSERT INTO `fields_leads` (`lead_id`, `field_id`, `vertical_id`, `offer_id`, `campaign_id`, `value`) VALUES ('56575', '866', '45', '82', '151', 'CharXX')

COMMIT
```

Meanwhile other transactions are taking place. Post trasaction the insertID of 56575 is used as keys in other tables for various business related stuffs.

Problem is when you go to look for leads.id=56575 its gone! There are no DELETE FROM `leads` statements in the general.log. No rollback statements regarding this query either. I'm running MySQL client version: 5.0.77. Any insight would be super helpful, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the inserts are being executed?, and are you sure they are not throwing any exception?. You should check your application log.

Comment: There's no way a mature database would just randomly lose data like this. And there's not enough information provided for us to tell what you're doing that's causing this.

Comment: From which transaction are you "looking for" the new records?  If it was one that started before the insertion transaction above was committed, you are likely in the (default) `REPEATABLE READ` [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-transaction.html).

Comment: Same sort of inserts happen hundreds of times a day, and randomly it drops a few. @eggyal The select statements are just setting up the insert statements. I'm using the insert id from that first insert statement as a key for other tables, so the ID has at least been generated, which I assume means it was a successful transaction.

Comment: @anakata yes no exceptions found or errors thrown. I have the database locally and can not reproduce the problem even under stress tests.

Comment: I'm not sure that you've answered my question: *From which transaction are you "looking for" the new records?*  In any event, I have another: what storage engine do these tables use?

Comment: please try to provide more details, and remember!!, always think you are the problem first, its very unlikely that the database is deleting the records, unless is the skynetDB, or something like that...

Comment: @anakata I'm always the problem. The thing is that I can't reproduce the problem consistently enough even with the same data that makes me think its a db bug or something I don't understand about transactions. What stuff do you want me to post?

Comment: you have concurrent transactions, have you tried using this ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @anakata that has to be it, im going to mark it as the answer, its the only thing that explains this behavior, thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe your SQL client (that you use to check the data) does not see those committed rows because the default isolation level is repeatable read. Try to run a `commit` or `rollback` before running the select to check for the rows.